# Flutter Application Performance on armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, flutter

So I was testing my application on [this](https://www.easyio.eu/products/hmi-products/sh-systemview10/), and noticed it was unbearably sluggish.

I tried installing a version specific to `armeabi-v7` by using split, but to no luck. After which I though maybe it was something wrong with my code so create a fresh new project and tried installing it. This also resulted in the same performance issue.

I tried looking for an issue regarding this in flutter's repo, but couldn't find any thing relevant. So am I missing something?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on macOS 11.1 20C69, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.2 at /Users/riteshakya037/Projects/flutter
    • Framework revision 84f3d28555 (3 months ago), 2020-10-15 16:26:19 -0700
    • Engine revision b8752bbfff
    • Dart version 2.10.2

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/riteshakya037/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/riteshakya037/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.2, Build version 12B45b
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1

 
[✓] Connected device (2 available)            
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • sdk phone armv7 (mobile)     • emulator-5556 • android-arm • Android 6.0 (API 23) (emulator)
```

Specs for the device can be found [this](https://www.easyio.eu/products/hmi-products/sh-systemview10/)

Comment: Have you seen/tried: https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance

Comment: Yeah I tried, still new to this whole profiling thing. @MorrisonChang. My main concern is that even the basic counter app was sluggish

Comment: I would definitely try to install some basic Java/Kotlin apps to see what is the tablet performance. My concern is that the hardware is 5 years old and now that would be considered a low-end or even depreciated device. Flutter is basically a game engine for CRUD apps so performance improvements by the Flutter team is on common recent hardware that have the Google Play Store. An OEM device like yours wouldn't be in their testing suite. Another thing to consider is that all of the 'cool features' for recent targetSDK libraries maybe too expensive performance wise on such a low end device.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for your input. I'll try loading a basic android app. Maybe its better if we just ditch it